# Spring Redis - get and deserialize list of objects stored as a single string in redis

Tags: java, spring, redis

For example, I have a serialized value like below stored as string in Redis, which represents a list of UserAction objects:

```
["java.util.ArrayList",[{"@class":"com.domain.UserAction","id":1,"name":"Login"},{"@class":"com.domain.UserAction","id":2,"name":"Logout"}]]
```

when I tried to access this via its key (e.g.`UserActionsCache`) via redisTemplate:

```
RedisTemplate<String, UserAction> redisTemplate;
redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
```

it throws an error like:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON:
Could not resolve type id `com.domain.UserAction` as a subtype of `java.lang.Object`: no such class found
```

i tried changing the `redisTemplate` to below, but it has the same issue:

```
RedisTemplate<String, List<UserAction>> redisTemplate;
RedisTemplate<String, ArrayList<UserAction>> redisTemplate;
RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
```

How do you properly access the value and deserialize it to a list of objects?

P.S. This is part of my redisTemplate config:

```
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
          p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnFactory"
          p:keySerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer"
          p:valueSerializer-ref="genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer"
          p:hashKeySerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer"
          p:hashValueSerializer-ref="genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I know this is old question but you can simply refactor your redisTemplate

I dont know what is the equivalent bean definition on spring but I'm leaving for spring boot.

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, List<UserAction>> redisTemplate() {

    final var redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, List<UserAction>>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());

    final var jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);

    final var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL,  JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);

    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

Then you can autowire related bean like this.

`RedisTemplate<String, List<UserAction>> redisTemplate`

For usage :

`redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("key");`

this must be work.